# Restrictions in a optimization using R

Tags: r, function, optimization, conditional-statements

Continuing the question made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57146134/7769755), I'd like to add a restriction in the optimization:

```
a <- c(52.67, 46.80, 41.74, 40.45)
b <- c(1.726219351, 1.842421805, 1.790801758, 1.449997494)

rsq <- function(c) {
  x <- log(a)
  y <- log((c*(a/b))-1)
  summary(lm(y ~ x))$r.squared
}
optimise(rsq, maximum = TRUE, interval=c(1, 1000))
```

The interval for the optimization is 1 to 1000, however I'd like that the interval starts where

```
(c*(a/b)) > 0
```

To avoid problems with `log`

Answer (score 1):

Just return -Inf if the log argument would be negative.  Then it is unnecessary to manipulate the domain.

```
rsq <- function(c) {
  x <- log(a)
  tmp <- (c*(a/b))-1
  if (any(tmp < 0)) -Inf else summary(lm(log(tmp) ~ x))$r.squared
}

optimise(rsq, maximum = TRUE, interval=c(1, 1000))
```

giving:

```
$maximum
[1] 1.082353

$objective
[1] 0.8093781
```

### Update

Fixed.